# Display pdf created on the fly on modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

*Summary in the end.

I read many many questions like mine here on SO and other sites to try and solve my problem, but I couldn't find the solution to the final bit of the problem.

**DESCRIPTION:**

I have a table (jqGrid) where I display some data from a database, like this:

```
+------+-----+
| Name | Age |
+------------+
| test |  1  |
+------+-----+
```

and I have a button that generates a PDF with information of the currently select row.

To accomplish this, when the user clicks on the button "PDF" I create a form with hidden inputs and set their values:

```
//create a form
$("<form>").attr({
   "id" : "invform",
   "method" : "post",
   "action" : "Home/generatePdf"
 });
```

Then I create the inputs and hide them and submit the form to the server...

```
//Id of selected row
var selectedRowId = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
//Value of column Name of selected row
var cellValue = $("#grid").jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'name');

$("#invform")
.append($("<input>").attr({"name" : "Name", "type" : "text", "value" : cellValue}))

//hide all inputs
$("#invform input").attr({"hidden" : "true"});

//submit form
$("#invform").submit();
```

The form is then sent to my controller and populates the obj with all the data:

```
public FileStreamResult generatePdf(Model obj)
{
 PDF myPdf = <code for generating the pdf>;

 byte[] byteArr = myPdf.toByteArray();

 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 ms.Write(byteArr, 0, byteArr.Length);

 HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
 "inline; filename=" + randomName + ".pdf"); //random name is just a string based on time etc

 return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
}
```

All this is working perfectly.

**PROBLEM:**

After I call submit() on the form, the controllers is called and the pdf is returned and displayed on the same tab. I need this form to be displayed on a modal window I have.

HTML:

```
<div id="pdfdiv" style="display:none">
    <iframe id="pdfframe" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#pdfdiv").dialog({
  height: ($(window).height() * 0.95),
  width: ($(window).width() * 0.45),
  position: {
    my: "center bottom",
    at: "center top",
    of: $(window)
  }
});
```

I don't know what to put on the "src" attribute of the iframe to make the pdf be displayed there and not on the sabe browser tab.
I feel like this is something easy to do and Im missing something because Im new to web development.

Summary: my pdf returned from the controller is being displayed on the same browser tab, I need to make it appear on a jquery dialog, but I dont know what to put in the iframe src attribute because the pdf is generated after a form is submitted.

Comment: in what browser? or browsers?

Comment: chrome. Pdf is in a memory stream.

Comment: Examine the JS here at http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf, there are options to open in a new window, download and embed in the actual document the PDF. There is also some browser sniffing happening to only give you what you can have depending on the browser.

Comment: This worked for me (PDF modal dialog from a byte[] via an MVC-ajax call)  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477525/stream-a-byte-to-load-inside-a-jquery-modal-as-pdf-mvc3/44630572#44630572>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
The idea here is that there is no way to capture the return of the method/action called by the form (attribute action). Instead, what I had to do was call the controller action from the iframe inside my dialog. I used the form because it was the easiest way to pass data to the controller as a complex object, but to do this from the iframe I had to assemble a URL with the parameters of the object and read them in the controller. I built the url with the parameters I needed (name=..&age=...) and dynamically set the iform src after the button to display the modal window was clicked, caused the action to return to the iframe and display my PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT create a form and call it's submit() method.

Use jQuery $.post() function like this in the click event of your button:

```
$.post("Home/generatePdf", {
   "id" : "invform", 
   "name" : "Name", 
   "type" : "text", 
   "value" : cellValue,

function( resp ) {
    //Success function
    //Reply with a JSON string from server indicating the PDF URL in the url property

    resp.url;   //this should cointain the URL to your generated PDF

},

"json"

});
```

This will avoid the PDF to be downloaded from the server to the browser.

On the "success function", open the modal and display the PDF.
You can use pdf.js library (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) to display the PDF inside the modal, remember that if you don't use this library (or similar) the PDF would not shown on browser unless a PDF reader extension is installed in the browser.

I'm assuming these PDF are generated on the server and can be downloaded later, otherwise you just can pass the URL to pdf.js in the click button handler instead of doing the $.post().

Also, Google docs viewer would be an alternative to show the PDF (either generated and stored on server or on the fly via an URL), if the PDF do not contains sensitive just use it like this inside your modal window, but be aware that the PDF gets transmitted to Google docs in order to be rendered, also the PDF URL must be public (not user/password needed to be accessed):

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=your-pdf-url.com/doc.pdf&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: isnt that just short for and $.ajax of type post? I read here that what I'm trying to do can't be accomplished using ajax request. Also, I don't have a URL to the pdf, if I had it I would just have done what you said. My pdf is in a memory stream, it is never materialized. I realize now that using the form is just impossile for what I'm trying to do. I need to call the Action from the iframe URL, and to fill out the pdf I will have to send a json of my complex object in the url, what I didn't want to do. However this is just one way, Im sure theres some simpler way to do this.