# PDF returned as byte array through ajax. Either getting ERR_INVALID_URL or blank pdf appears depending on parameters

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, pdf, google-chrome-extension, base64

Code from spring controller that is sending the byte array (pdf) back to ajax call

```
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-control", "private");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");;

    if (pdf != null) {
        response.setContentLength(pdf.length);
        ServletOutputStream out;
        try {
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(pdf);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This pdf is added dynamically to a dialog that can be opened later. "data" contains the byte array

```
var obj = $('<object width=100% height=100% style="float:left;"'
                        + ' type="application/pdf"'
                        + ' data="data:application/pdf,'
                        + escape(data)
                        + '"></object>');  
                $('#adjDialog'+rapRow).append(obj);
```

The result of this is it appears the pdf is converted using a chrome extension but the data attribute is not properly set. I see an empty PDF in a PDF viewer and when I inspect it with developer tools I can find this markup (didn't write this, generated by chrome)

```
    <embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="data:" 
stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/E4E5DEA1-
DDF5-4300-9C43-8634ED843E50" headers="" background-color="0xFF525659" top-
toolbar-height="56">
```

^data is empty but I would expect it should be the url I provided.

If I add ";base64" to data attribute nothing loads and I get

```
GET data:application/pdf;base64,%25PDF-1.4%0A%25%uFFFD%uFFFD%uFFFD%uFFFD%0A1%20…431343532353232343430323633%3E%5D%3E%3E%0Astartxref%0A84512%0A%25%25EOF%0A net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

I've been taking hints from several different code examples on stack overflow but nothing seems quite like mine. I'm not using any PHP, no database, and I'm not saving the file on the server

Comment: General solution: This worked for me (PDF modal dialog from a byte[] via an MVC-ajax call)  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477525/stream-a-byte-to-load-inside-a-jquery-modal-as-pdf-mvc3/44630572#44630572>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by just having the html attribute "data" point to the http request that built the pdf response instead of doing an ajax call separately and trying to patch in the result.